# How do you use a cursor to combine data in a Union All?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of databases, say 'database1, database2, database3'. Etc.

At the moment I am querying my results by doing

```
select column1 from database1..tableA
union all
select column1 from database2..tableA
union all 
select column1 from database3..tableA
```

Is there a better way of doing this using sp_foreachdb or a cursor with a list of databases?

Comment: Dynamic query is the answer

Comment: Not really, if you want one resultset. You could build that query with dynamic SQL or some client language (C#?)

Answer (score 3):

You can query the list of databases from `sys.databases`. Then you use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'UNION ALL SELECT column1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '..tableA' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

SELECT @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '')

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Blorgbeard commented above, the union all you have there is the way to go if you want one resultset. But if you don't want one result set or want to play with sp_foreachdb, you could try tweaking this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_Id) FROM sys.tables where DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')'
```